# Java Class.forName failing

Tags: java, reflection

I cannot seem to get `Class.forName(String)` to not throw a `ClassNotFoundException`. For example, this code which is a shortened copy of [code directly from Sun's website](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/index.html#3) throws the exception.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
class A {}

public class Test {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      try {
         Class cls = Class.forName("A");
      }
      catch (Throwable e) {
         System.err.println(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Produces

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: A

I am using Eclipse 1.3.2.20110218-0812 on Windows XP SP3. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: It worked for me. No exception at all.

Comment: how do you run it ? Working for me too

Comment: Probably by having Test not in the default package, so even if A is defined just above Test, for the classloader it has to be fully qualified including package name of the Test class.

Comment: is this the **complete** code? not missing the `package` line?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to prepend the package name of the Test class to A, as an example if Test were in "test" package, you'd need following:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("test.A");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your snippet works fine for me.

Here is a demo at ideone.com: http://ideone.com/IBjKl

Note that you need to provide the **fully qualified name** of the class for the class loader to find it. I.e., if `A` is actually in some package, you need to do `forName("your.package.A")` for it to work.

(Note that the import is unnecessary.)

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName` function needs the fully specified class path. So even if you have imported `ArrayList` from `java.util` you should use:

```
Class myClass = Class.forName("java.util.ArrayList");
```

that is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you need to have a class with name "A" in your classpath