# Cannot instantiate class from interface

Tags: java

I have the following interface in the application I am building:

```
package sistemata;

public interface PaymentgatewayAdapter
{   
    public String postPayment(String a);
}
```

And the following class implements it:

```
public class PaypalAdapter implements PaymentgatewayAdapter
{
    public String postPayment(String a)
    {

        String payAmount;
        String transactionOutcome;
        String response;
        payAmount = a;

        Paypal_sim systemGN = new Paypal_sim();
        System.out.println("v adaptera" + a);
        //Simulerar att data skickas till externa systemet
        response = systemGN.transferSaleData(payAmount);

        if (response == "OK")
        {
            transactionOutcome = "OK";
        }
        else
        {
            transactionOutcome = "Invalid data sent to MasterCard.";
        }

        return transactionOutcome;
        //------------------------------
    }
}
```

There is a second, almost identical class called Payson, but it is not used. 
This interface is part of a `ServicesFactory`:

```
package sistemata;

public class ServicesFactory
{
    private static ServicesFactory instance;
    private PaymentgatewayAdapter paymentAdapter;

    private String className2;

    public static synchronized ServicesFactory getInstance()
    {
        instance = new ServicesFactory();
        return instance;
    }


    public PaymentgatewayAdapter getPaymentAdapter(String className2) 
    {
        this.className2 = className2;

        if (paymentAdapter == null)
        {
            try
            {
                paymentAdapter = (PaymentgatewayAdapter)
                        Class.forName(className2).newInstance();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot instantiate: " +
                        className2 + ".");
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        return paymentAdapter;  
    }
}
```

The method `getPaymentAdapter` is called in `Account` class, like this:

```
else if (paymentMethod == 0)
{
    System.out.println("The payment method is PayPal INC");
    String className = "PaypalAdapter";
    paymentAdapter = ServicesFactory.getInstance().getPaymentAdapter(className);
}
```

Whenever I call:

```
paymentAdapter = ServicesFactory.getInstance().getPaymentAdapter(className);
```

I get the error that is thrown in  `System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot instantiate:.`
Whatever I try, I cannot work around this and I cannot find solution. I will be thankful for some help with this code, or even suggestions to hardcode.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PaymentgatewayAdapter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at sistemata.ServicesFactory.getPaymentAdapter(ServicesFactory.java:26)
    at sistemata.Account.makePayment(Account.java:56)
    at sistemata.MainSystem.main(MainSystem.java:71)
```

Comment: Did you show all the constructors, if any, for `PaypalAdapter`? And what comes next on the stack trace please?

Comment: Can you add a Stacktrace?

Comment: Your custom-made error message is much less useful than the stacktrace you're printing right after it.  Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Yes, all important constructors are in here, the main idea is to implement ProtectedVariations and in such a way - have two external methods for payment

Comment: You need to use fully qualified name with `Class.forName()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Class.forName failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803369/java-class-forname-failing)

Comment: Can you show the exact message?

Comment: I will update it with stack i na sec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you forget the package name from this line?

```
String className = "PaypalAdapter";
```

should it be

```
String className = "sistemata.x.y.z.PaypalAdapter";
```

Comment: It's best to use `PaypalAdapter.class.getName()` IMHO

Comment: @RC If you're going to use a class literal you might as well just `newInstance()` it yourself right there.

Comment: @RC Yes, or perhaps even `public PaymentgatewayAdapter getPaymentAdapter(Class clazz)` and then pass `PaypalAdapter.class`

Comment: TomG, in current context, but I agree. vikingsteve event better :)

Comment: yes, I am totally blind - it needs the folder.Classname All the time I was focusing in the confusing abstract class insead of checking out this :X

Answer (score 2):

The class name you pass to `Class.forName()` must be a fully-qualified class name, including the package. Try using "sistema.PaypalAdapter".

Comment: ahhh i just do not beleive how blind I am, i really missed this - and now all works fine